# Tensorflow encoder-decoder dynamic lstm with variable length inputs and outputs

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm

I am implementing an encoder-decoder LSTM network that should reconstruct the input sequence.

Currently, I am getting an error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

I think it happens because I feed variable length inputs as part of `feed_dict`.

This is the function responsible for constructing feed dictionary:

```
def next_feed(batch_index):
    encoder_inputs_ = train_X[batch_index:batch_index + train_batch_size]          # encoder input = [w1, w2, ...]
    encoder_inputs_length_ = seq_lengths[batch_index: batch_index + train_batch_size]
    decoder_targets_ = []
    for i in range(encoder_inputs_.shape[0]):
        l = seq_lengths[batch_index: batch_index + train_batch_size][i]
        trimmed = np.array(encoder_inputs_[i, 0:l+1])
        decoder_targets_.append(trimmed)
    decoder_targets_ = np.array(decoder_targets_)
    return {
        encoder_inputs: encoder_inputs_,
        decoder_targets: decoder_targets_,
        encoder_inputs_length: encoder_inputs_length_
    }
```

If I do not trim the `decoder_targets` that I get another error, because dimensions of `logits` and `labels` do not match:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[16,7810] labels_size=[550,7810]
```

**Question**: how to handle this error? Ideally I would like to stick to trimmed `decoder_targets`.

**EDIT**: Is padding the only way to deal with such cases?